# Displaying Vectortile Source using ngx-openlayers

Tags: openlayers, vector-tiles, angular

I downloaded a tileset from [OpenMapTiles](https://openmaptiles.org/) and host it with [tileserver-gl](https://github.com/maptiler/tileserver-gl), what is working just fine. Now I want to load and display the vector tiles in an Angular 7 application using [ngx-openlayers](https://github.com/quentin-ol/ngx-openlayers), but am not sure how to achieve this.

### What I did so far

Setting up the tileserver with the following `config.json`:

```
{
  "options": {
    "paths": {
      "root": "",
      "fonts": "fonts",
      "styles": "styles",
      "mbtiles": "tiles"
    }
  },
  "styles": {
    "positron": {
      "style": "positron/style.json",
      "tilejson": {
        "format": "pbf"
      }
    }
  },
  "data": {
    "v3": {
      "mbtiles": "2017-07-03_europe_germany.mbtiles"
    }
  }
}
```

After starting the tileserver listening on the default port, [localhost:8080](http://localhost:8080/) shows the following:
[image]
"Positron" is the style I want to use for rendering the vector data.

Inside the Angular template I tried to load the vector tiles as following:

```html
<aol-map>
    <aol-view 
        [zoom]="mapState.zoom"
        [minZoom]="5"
        [maxZoom]="17"
    >
        <aol-coordinate
            [x]="mapState.coordinates.latitude"
            [y]="mapState.coordinates.longitude"
            [srid]="'EPSG:4326'"
        >
    </aol-view>
    <aol-layer-vectortile [style]="mapStyle" [renderMode]="'vector'">
        <aol-source-vectortile [tileUrlFunction]="tileUrlFunction">
            <aol-format-mvt></aol-format-mvt>
            <aol-tilegrid></aol-tilegrid>
            <aol-attributions>...</aol-attributions>
        </aol-source-vectortile>
    </aol-layer-vectortile>
</aol-map>
```

Inside the Angular component, I define `mapStyle` like this:

```
public mapStyle: ol.style.Style = require("src/style.json");
```

However, I am not sure how to define `tileUrlFunction`, or if I am on the right way at all.
When I render the "Positron" style on the server and serve it as png, I can display the map as a normal tile layer without any problem.